# Jquery adding id to a span

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net

I am working on asp.net mvc website where we have validation messages generated inside span dynamically on button click. I am trying to assign id to span and failed doing that.

What I tried is

```
Before button click

<span class="field-validation-error" id="prjTitle" data-valmsg-for="Title" data-valmsg-replace="true">

</span>

after button click
<span class="field-validation-error" id="prjTitle" data-valmsg-for="Title" data-valmsg-replace="true">

<span for="Title">Enter Project Title</span>

</span>


Jquery code:
 $('#btnSubmit').click(function () {
        // Adding ids to Validation Messages 
        $('#prjTitle span').attr('id', 'prjTitle1');
});
```

Could some one suggest me on how to add id to dynamically generated span

Comment: the possibility is the span is created after your click handler is executed.... also it might be created in the form submit handler not the submit button click handler... try `$('#btnSubmit').click(function () {
        // Adding ids to Validation Messages 
        setTimeout(function(){$('#prjTitle span').attr('id', 'prjTitle1');}, 50)
});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated** : Here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/surendrans/N5LtZ/1/ using [jquery.waituntilexists.js](https://gist.github.com/buu700/4200601)

```
<span class="field-validation-error" id="prjTitle" data-valmsg-for="Title" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
<input type= button id="btnSubmit" value="Submit">


 $('#btnSubmit').click(function () {
            // Adding ids to Validation Messages 
         setTimeout(function(){
         $("#prjTitle").append('<span for="Title">Enter Project Title</span>');
         },3000);
    $("#prjTitle span").waitUntilExists(function() {
    $("#prjTitle span").addClass('newid')
    });  
    });
```

Comment: as span is dynamically generated, this is not working.

Comment: @Usham i misunderstood your question, is your span gets created after the button is clicked?.

Comment: Yes its a general behaviour of asp.net mvc model validation. It creates a validation message inside a dynamically generated span.

Comment: This did not work for me. I tried your code with static span which works, but this fails because span is dynamically created. jsfiddle.net/N5LtZ

Comment: @Usham May be the span is created after the click event gets executed, there is a small jquery library jquery.waituntilexists.js, I am updating my answer using that library.